# How to start two firefox instances in series

Tags: firefox, multiple-instances

I would like to start two firefox windows one after another, but this wont work:

```
firefox -p test & firefox --new-instance -p test &
```

Because it throws an error and the second instance wont open

[image]

Comment: Use the correct terminology: "new instance" is not same as "new window"; title and description are saying two different things; which one? Firefox has separate options for these two. Run `man firefox` or `firefox --help` in Terminal to check for yourself.